# Generating A Dropdown Menu from an API call in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu, populate

I'm a beginner programmer in PHP. For practice, I'm calling an API from A View From My Seat (www.aviewfrommyseat.com), which is a website that lets people upload pictures taken from their seats at certain venues.

What I would like to write is an application where people type in the venue name, and a dropdown list will immediately come up with a list of available sections. There is an API to call the sections, but I need to figure out the proper syntax to populate the list. I Frankenstein-ed together some code from other Stack Overflow answers I've found, but nothing is really working.\

Anyway, here is the list I'm trying to access -- the different sections of each venue.
[image]

Here's the first part of the PHP code (fetches the URL)

```
if (!empty($_GET['venue'])) {
    $venue_url = 'https://aviewfrommyseat.com/avf/api/venue.php?appkey=API_KEY&venue=' . urlencode($_GET['venue']) . '&section_list=true';
$venue_json = file_get_contents($venue_url);
$venue_array = json_decode($venue_json, true);
    }
?>
```

This second part is the actual HTML section with the button.

```
<body>
    <h1> Search for a Venue</h1>
<div class = "middle_box">
    <p> Enter in a venue to get more info about it and to view available    sections. </p>
<form action="">
    <input type = "text" name = "venue" />
    <button type="submit">submit </button>
</form>
```

And here is where I try to use PHP to populate the different sections that pop up:

```
<?php
if(!empty($venue_array)) { 
    echo "<p> Here are the available sections for {$venue_array['avfms'][0]['name']}. Select one to view seats. </p>";
    echo "<select name =\"section\" id =\"section\"> 
      <option selected=\"selected\">Choose one</option>
foreach($venue_array['avfms'][0]['section'] as $section) {
  <option value=\"<?= $section['section']\">< $section['section']></option>\"
    </select>";
}
 ?>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: why are you trying to do a `foreach` loop inside your `echo` statement?

Comment: I want the code to loop through each 'section' and form it into an <option> tag. I was thinking that maybe I should be using 'while' instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're trying to execute a `foreach` loop inside an `echo` statement.

```
    echo "<select name =\"section\" id =\"section\"> 
      <option selected=\"selected\">Choose one</option>
foreach($venue_array['avfms'][0]['section'] as $section) {
  <option value=\"<?= $section['section']\">< $section['section']></option>\"
    </select>";
```

Try separating that out:

```
<?php
if(!empty($venue_array)) { 
    echo "<p> Here are the available sections for {$venue_array['avfms'][0]['name']}. Select one to view seats. </p>";
    // open select
    echo "<select name =\"section\" id =\"section\"> 
      <option selected=\"selected\">Choose one</option>";

   // start loop
   foreach($venue_array['avfms'][0]['section'] as $section)
     echo "<option value=\"$section\"> $section </option>\"";

    // close select
    echo "</select>";
}
 ?>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also note that you're declaring a variable `$section` from

```
foreach($venue_array['avfms'][0]['section'] as $section)
```

... so it's strange to me that you're referencing the value as an array index:

```
<option value=\"<?= $section['section']\">< $section['section']></option>\"
```

... and you shouldn't need the `<?=` while already inside a quoted string, so I dropped that from my example.